# Why is my linux syscall returning a -1 in userspace?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I tried many guides and for some reason, my syscall isn't even returning a 0 as it should. Where am I going wrong? Here are my steps to creating one:

inside "/linux/" folder: 
I created a folder called "mycall" with files mycall.c, mycall.h, & Makefile

mycall.c:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <syscalls.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include "mycall.h"

asmlinkage long sys_mysyscall(int *id, int username, int *size)
{
 printk("hello");
 return 0;
}
```

mycall.h:

```
asmlinkage long sys_mysyscall(int *id, int username, int *size);
```

Makefile:

```
obj-y := mycall.o
```

then I went into all of the places where I THOUGHT i should declare the syscall.

```
// inside of /linux/include/linux/syscalls.h
asmlinkage long sys_mysyscall(int __user *myid, int username, int __user *size);
```

then to

```
// inside of /linux/arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl
398    common  mysyscall      sys_mysyscall
```

finally i added

```
// inside of /linux/Makefile
core-y    += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypt/ block/ mycall/
```

thats my set up. then the final thing I do is make a userspace in /linux directory
userspace.c:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main () 
{
int id = 0;
int username = 7;
int size = 2;
int ret_val = syscall(398, &id, username, &size);
printf("%d\n", ret_val);
return 0;
}
```

the return value is -1 so this doesn't work. please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I have read several implementation guides.

ERRNO is 38 . Function not implemented.

Comment: What is the `errno` value?

Comment: have you looked for errno, have you used strace command, what are the results

Comment: @KamilCuk could you help me where I would check the errno value? (Haven't used that before). Am googling what it is.

Comment: `#include <errno.h>`  
`#include <string.h>`  
(...)
`printf("ERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));`

Comment: @AdamTL thank you ! I have updated my post to show the errno

Comment: errno 38 is ENOSYS.  Your system call hasn't made it into the kernel's table of system calls, so you've apparently missed something.  You did recompile and reboot?  You're sure you are running the modified kernel?  Are you in fact running on ARM?

Comment: Not to be rude, but it may be premature to try to get into kernel hacking before you have a pretty good comfort level with userspace Unix programming.  Knowing about `errno` is pretty fundamental.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks, I'll investigate further. & It's not rude. I should've had mentioned that this is a small part of coursework & we're being used as guinea pigs so yes I'm barely learning everything from scratch. No other course I've taken before taught me kernel hacking.

Comment: This may be a silly question, but are you actually running the updated kernel?