# What is missing in my syscall implementation?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I tried many guides and for some reason, my syscall isnt implementing correctly. ERRNO is 38 (function not implemented).  Here are my steps to creating a basic one for me as a beginner:

I am doing this on a raspberry pi 64 bit. with linux 4.14.93

inside "/linux/" folder: 
I created a folder called "mycall" with files mycall.c, mycall.h, & Makefile

mycall.c:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <syscalls.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include "mycall.h"

asmlinkage long sys_mysyscall(int *id, int username, int *size)
{
 printk("hello");
 return 0;
}
```

mycall.h:

```
asmlinkage long sys_mysyscall(int *id, int username, int *size);
```

Makefile:

```
obj-y := mycall.o
```

then I went into all of the places where I THOUGHT i should declare the syscall.

```
// inside of /linux/include/linux/syscalls.h
asmlinkage long sys_mysyscall(int __user *myid, int username, int __user *size);
```

then to

```
// inside of /linux/arch/arm/tools/syscall.tbl
398    common  mysyscall      sys_mysyscall
```

finally i added

```
// inside of /linux/Makefile
core-y    += kernel/ certs/ mm/ fs/ ipc/ security/ crypt/ block/ mycall/
```

thats my set up. then the final thing I do is make a userspace in /linux directory
userspace.c:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>

int main () 
{
int id = 0;
int username = 7;
int size = 2;
int ret_val = syscall(398, &id, username, &size);
printf("%d\n", ret_val);
return 0;
}
// recompiling & copying . then I run the userspace again
cd ~/linux
KERNEL=kernel7
make bcm2709_defconfig
make -j4 zImage modules dtbs
sudo make INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/root modules_install

sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/*.dtb /boot/
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/*.dtb* /boot/overlays/
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/README /boot/overlays/
sudo cp arch/arm/boot/zImage /boot/$KERNEL.img
```

the return value is -1 so this doesn't work.

please let me know what I'm doing wrong. I have read several implementation guides and have no idea how I'm implementing this wrong.

Comment: After `syscall` fails, have you checked `errno`?

Comment: This has already been asked (but not yet answered) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492440/why-is-my-linux-syscall-returning-a-1-in-userspace